# How can I use the Razor editor found in Visual Studio 2019 in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: html, razor, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

[image]

[image]

Visual studio 2022 does not align code. Code suggestions do not work in HTML pages.

I want like this.

[image]

I try a lot of solutions but doesnt work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Tools → Options → Text Editor → HTML → Advanced and set the "Use legacy Razor editor for ASP.NET Core" to true.

[image: Enabled Legacy Razor Editor]